# How to get params values in next page

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar, laravel-mix-vue3

In quasar i am using a button

`<q-btn unelevated rounded color="positive" label="Next"  icon-right="send" class="full-width" @click="goToCustomer">`

Here is my function in setup

```
  const goToCustomer = function (){
      router.push({
        name: 'ITEM', path: '/item', params: { mycustomer: mycustomer}
      })
    }
```

i am passing a array through params
Array is like this

```
const Customerselected = function(id, name ){
  mycustomer.value.splice(0)
  mycustomer.value.push({ id, name })
}
```

How i get mycustomer array in item page?

I tried `{{ this.$route.params.mycustomer }}`

And the result is

```
[object Object]
```

How i get values in the array?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

if you are using script setup

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

const route = useRoute();

=> route.params // Is this what you look for?
```

Comment: I tried   <div class="q-mt-sm">
    {{ $route.params.mycustomer }}
  </div>. but no use. kept import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'     const router = useRouter() in item page

Comment: What is the result

Comment: didnt display anything. In cosole it shows vue-router.mjs:35 [Vue Router warn]: Path "/item" was passed with params but they will be ignored. Use a named route alongside params instead.

Comment: can you show me definition of your routes

Comment: { path: '/item', props: true, component: () => import('pages/itemPage.vue') },